# How to animate specific frames of a motion sequence in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, frames, motion

[image]I have a motion sequence of N frames and i have the code to animate it(not my code).I can animate all the frames or a range, or a range with K step from start to the end.

the result is showing the movement without caching any frame and stopping at the last one.
What i want is to have more than the last frame in my figure.for example the first the one in the middle and the last at the same figure  like a movement that keeps all the frames visible in one plot!!.

How can i do this?furthermore , i can save individual frames as individual images in the memory, but can i  save them as a motion sequence(from the images) or have them in one figure as one plot(don't need subplots).

If needed i can give the code of the animation.

Comment: You should probably share a reproducible example.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Do you actually want an animation/movie or do you just want to display all of your frames at once as an image or set of images?

Comment: I have a motion sequence of 200 frames that shows a human skeleton(lines connect joints)rotating his arms while staying at the same point(legs not  moving).I have the code animate that shows one frame each time as a movie,also i can save individual frames as images, but i want for example 10 frames to be showed  to the figure simultaneously so i can have the arms at a different position each time

Comment: i have added an example at my question to see what do i mean.i have the code that shows the above movement but it doesn't keep the intermediate frames at the figure.that is what i want, to have the intermediate frames at my figure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have plot data in vectors `x` and `y`, for each time point, say `x(:,i)` gives the x-coordinates at the `i`-th time step, then something like this will give each x-y plot for each value of `t` stacked on top of each other. This code may not do exactly what you were asking fo, but hopefully it gets you going.

```
figure(1)
hold on
for i=1:length(t)
    plot3(x(:,i),y(:,i),t(i)*ones(length(t),1))
end
hold off
```